# How to solve this?

Tags: edit-mode

I am using a MacBook Air M1 and I would be immensely grateful if anybody could tell me how to use + / - on the keyboard (which I mostly use in Edit Model in combination to Command Select more/Select less vertex/edges/faces), since my device hasn’t a numpad.

As you can see from the enclosed screenshot I have already attempted to open Blender Preferences and change the input keys, although it seems not to work.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Yes, I have already followed this procedure and set the keys Command and 9/7 to Select More and Command 0/8 to Select less as you kindly suggest, but this is not working...

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

just press on the right button and choose whatever key you want.

I have chosen command+ to do this action like this:

[image]

[image]